# What is the range of a Mage's Alter Time?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Alter Time**
>
> Alter the fabric of time, causing the caster to return to their current location, health, mana, buffs, and debuffs, when cast a second time, or after 6 sec.
> Effect negated if the caster dies within the 6 sec before the effect occurs or *moves too far away*.

When looking at [the spell](http://mop.wowhead.com/spell=108978) or [the buff](http://mop.wowhead.com/spell=110909) for Alter Time, neither actually mentions the range that counts as "too far away." How many yards away from the casting position is a Mage allowed to move before Alter Time no longer works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4063167982) (based on user testing) states that the maximum range that this will work over is 100 yards - seemingly. They're speculating that this essentially works as 'whatever distance you cover while the effect is up' but won't undo actions like taking a portal, for example.

Keep in mind it is beta though, so is subject to change.